# Unable to get text from div span element in jsoup

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

So, I'm web scraping Udemy to get the all the details about the course which is on sale for free through the link where I used to get price (free or not) if free then title of the course, time remaining, rating of the course etc.

It was all working fine but suddenly it started giving me **NullPointerException** whenever it was trying to get the price of the course.

Element is as follow

```
<div class="price-text--price-part--Tu6MH udlite-clp-discount-price udlite-heading-xxl" data-purpose="course-price-text">
 <span class="udlite-sr-only">Current price</span>
  <span>Free</span>
</div>
```

And this is how I was scraping it with the help of JSOUP

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(mainUrl).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36").get();
String price = document.select("div.price-text--price-part--Tu6MH").first().text();

            if (!price.contains("Free")) {
                System.out.println("\nCoupon Expired...");
            } else {
                further code...
            }
```

But, now I'm not able to, I did lot of R&D but still unable to do it. Can someone please help me with it ?

I want is to get the **FREE** value.

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow (all of the Stack Exchange Network) must be self-contained. The primary purpose of Stack Overflow is for questions to be useful to future visitors. Questions which require users to go offsite to get more information are not useful to future visitors, particularly once the off-site resource changes. This question might be good/useful, but you need to move enough code into the question so we know what you're asking without needing to go off-site to find out. Please see: [this question on Meta Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428), which has more info.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example code which should help you. I have used the Jsoup.parse but you can use Jsoup.connect and use the code

> String price = doc.select("div.price-text--price-part--Tu6MH").select("span:nth-last-child(1)").text()

or

> String price = doc.select("div.price-text--price-part--Tu6MH >
> span:nth-last-child(1)").text();

```
String html = "<html><body><div class=\"price-text--price-part--Tu6MH udlite-clp-discount-price udlite-heading-xxl\" data-purpose=\"course-price-text\">\r\n" + 
                      " <span class=\"udlite-sr-only\">Current price</span>\r\n" + 
                      "  <span>Free</span>\r\n" + 
                      "</div></body></html>";
  Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
  String price = doc.select("div.price-text--price-part--Tu6MH > span:nth-last-child(1)").text();
  System.out.println(price);
  if (!price.contains("Free")) {
      System.out.println("\nCoupon Expired...");
  } else {
      System.out.println("Its free");
  }
```

Comment: I tried your first solution but it didn't worked, coming on the 2nd solution so link will always be changing.

for example now link is https://www.udemy.com/course/stock-trading-cryptocurrency-trading-technical-analysis/?couponCode=C36ABB66A5C047AB6AA1
but next time it'll be different and I've to check if the course is free or not

Comment: @Akash You use Jsoup.connect to connect any url you want. If the html structure is same in each page , like you shown in the example. You can do above. But which url you are reading if that has the html if its legal to read that url, those are something you have to take care of.

Comment: forget about everything, can you please help me getting the the "Free" text with java code from https://www.udemy.com/course/stock-trading-cryptocurrency-trading-technical-analysis/?couponCode=C36ABB66A5C047AB6AA1 this link ?

Comment: @Akash Lt me suggest you something. Whatever url you are trying to access , read the html of that page in java and see if you have that html in the page, lot of content in the pages these days come through javascript or ajax, your jsoup call will not do those. You have to use something like selenium for that.

Comment: I tried but not working, what is surprising me the most is that it was working perfectly fine before (was using it from last 1-2 months) but suddenly it started giving me NullPointerException